# Django Admin replace field with ModelChoiceField with specific query

Tags: python, django, admin

I searched the net but did not find an answer - but I also a bloody beginner.

I basically have to models from two apps, but I don´t want to make a relation between both because of dependencies.

By creating an new sensor object in admin panel, I want that you only can choose between existing customer_names(Customer). I managed to override the field "owner" ins Sensor Admin panel and Django is also saving the values in the database. But everytime I revisit a sensor object in admin panel, owner is showing the default value "--" and I have to choose an owner.

(Sensor App)models.py

```
class Sensor(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
```

(Customer App)models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):  
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, unique=True)
```

forms.py

```
class SensorAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Customer.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        
        model = Sensor
        fields = '__all__'
```

admin.py

```
class SensorAdmin(OSMGeoAdmin):
   list_display = ('owner',)
   form = SensorAdminForm

admin.site.register(SensorRec, SensorRecAdmin)
```

Comment: I haven't used ModelChoiceField in this way, but I'm guessing `Sensor.owner` might have to be a `IntegerField` instead of `CharField`, since the value of the forms.ModelChoiceField would be a Customer.id, which is an integer, not a string.

Comment: You could also try `owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Customer.objects.all(), field='customer_name')`, though I don't know what happens if you have duplicate customer names.

Comment: The best solution might be to fix whatever your "because of dependencies" problem is, so you can use a proper foreign key here.

Comment: I edited customer_name with "unique=True". But when I try ur solution I get a "TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field'"

Comment: Sorry. The keyword name should be `to_field_name`, not `field`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name

Comment: Awh man I love u, this worked for me - thank you very much
````
owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Customer.objects.all(), to_field_name='customer_name')
````
I totaly oversee this at django documentation.